# Cherrypy application running on apache server getting socket errors

Tags: python, apache, cherrypy

When trying to launch a cherrypy website on an Apache server, no matter what port I select, I always get an error saying: "No socket could be created".

I used netstat to verify the port I am trying to connect to is listening.  Is there some sort of configuration necessary to get the application to run on an Apache server?  I have very little experience with cherrypy or Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Cherrypy is a framework for handling http-requests - it's actually designed to run as a standalone webserver. Thus it has overlapping functionality with apache, and you have to make a choice:

1. Skip cherrypy and let apache load your python script using [mod_python](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/). This will allow apache to run your python code very fast, without the overhead of cgi. Apache will call the `handler(req)` function in your code, and hand you all the request info via `req`. Django uses this approach.
2. Keep both, but let apache handle the listening, and define your port in the apache config file (i.e. httpd.conf). Then [read more about cherrypy behind apache](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/BehindApache)
3. Skip apache and use cherrypy as a standalone web server

I have good experience with 1, but all of them should be fine.

Comment: CherryPy can indeed run on its own but it's not compulsory and usually it sits behind another web server to handle static files for instance. Moreover mod_python is really not advised these days, better use mod_wsgi or a reverse proxy.

Comment: Yes, like I wrote, it can be run standalone, or behind a web server. I hear people talking about wsgi, but I don't really see the big reward, unless you really need your application to run on several different web servers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The reward is just that, being able to swap servers. I'll grant you it's not something you will do on a daily basis but it can be handy when one server shows issues on a particular aspect of HTTP.